# Shiftleft - Script Convert Blazemeter from command?

Tags: loadrunner, blazemeter, taurus

Exist some way where can I use [Script Convert](https://shiftleft.blazemeter.com/) from command line? I want to automatizate it executing the yaml file generated by shiftlef and then execute Taurus from jenkins job.
My issue is which I cant execute the convert and download the yaml file generated by shiftlef automatizated, because we need to inmediatly execute the yaml file in Blazemeter.
By now, I converting LoadRunner script and SoapUI and this script is very useful by me.
I hope can you help me :)!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible but what you could try is automating with selenium or similar tools the use of this webpage.

maybe you can ask Blazemeter support.